# Working with MultipartFile in Spring MVC 5 always return null

Tags: java, spring

I can not upload an Image to a specific directory in my server. the multipartfile variable always is empty, here my code

Config Bean

```
 @Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver()
{
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

Domain Class

```
private MultipartFile producImage;

public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
    return producImage;
}

public void setProducImage(MultipartFile producImage) {
    this.producImage = producImage;
}
```

Controller Class

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/products/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processAddNewProductForm(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") Product newProduct, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String[] suppressedFields = result.getSuppressedFields();
    if(suppressedFields.length > 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Attempting to bind disallowed fields " + StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(suppressedFields));
    }
    // productImage always receive null value !!!!!!
    MultipartFile productImage = newProduct.getProductImage();
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    if(productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory + "resources\\images\\" + newProduct.getProductId() + ".png"));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Product Image Saving failed", ex);
        }
    }

    productService.addProduct(newProduct);
    return "redirect:/market/products";
}
```

FrontEnd: addproduct.jsp

```
  <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="newProduct" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Add New Product</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="productImage">
                        <spring:message code="addProduct.form.productImage.label" />
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file" class="form:input-large" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" value ="Add"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form:form>
```

I dont know why is not working. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize a bean of type MultipartFilter and set the multipart resolver, giving Spring the ability to handle requests containing files:

```
@Bean
public MultipartFilter multipartFilter(){

    MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
    multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
    return multipartFilter;
}
```

Comment: You add the bean in the spring context configuration and voila, problem solved!

Comment: I added this bean and unfortunately voila didn't happen. still doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry Salar Ahmadi, your solution works fine. Thank you for your help.